# putting javascript variable in a html link included within javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I want a simple way to  display a picture in html within a google maps infobox from a variable in javascipt. Currently the infobox displays the image link:

```
var address = xmldata.getElementsByTagName('postalCode')[0].firstChild.data;
var picture = xmldata.getElementsByTagName('viewItemURL')[0].firstChild.data;
var info_text = picture + '<br />' + address;
```

I have tried

```
var info_text = address + '<a href="picture"></a>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
var info_text = address + '<img src="'+picture+'" alt="some alt text" />';
```